# vsts xunit vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, frameworks, azure-devops, xunit

I have a problem running XUnit Tests through VSTS build (private hosted agent), only when a test fails :

```
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1110631Z ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1111003Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1111532Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.138.6
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1111747Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseUri=undefined
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1111982Z ##[debug]Release.ReleaseId=undefined
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1112201Z ##[debug]Build.BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/3003
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1112402Z ##[debug]Build.Buildid=3003
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1112593Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.138.6
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1113027Z ##[debug]telemetry area: TestExecution feature: TestExecutionTask data: {"builduri":"vstfs:///Build/Build/3003","buildid":"3003","areacode":"ExecuteVsTest","result":"C:\\VSTSAgents\\AgentJ\\_work\\_tool\\VsTest\\15.8.0\\x64\\tools\\net451\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1","tracepoint":1005,"isusererror":true}
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1379570Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TestExecution;feature=TestExecutionTask;]{"builduri":"vstfs:///Build/Build/3003","buildid":"3003","areacode":"ExecuteVsTest","result":"C:\\VSTSAgents\\AgentJ\\_work\\_tool\\VsTest\\15.8.0\\x64\\tools\\net451\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\TestPlatform\\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1","tracepoint":1005,"isusererror":true}
2018-08-23T09:44:00.1386171Z ##[error]Error: C:\VSTSAgents\AgentJ\_work\_tool\VsTest\15.8.0\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe failed with return code: 1
```

The first line is a warning telling there is a test that fails => it's ok
The last line is an error that makes the task to stop the build chain.

I don't know why it does that and how to avoid this behavior. I would like to be able to continue my build chain after this step and I don't think that checking "continue on error" is a solution.

## Task configuration :

- Type : Visual Studio Test
- Select tests using : Test assemblies
- Test platforme version : installed by tools installer (I have a Visual Studio Test Platform installer task just beyond)
- run tests in isolation : checked
- code coverage enabled : checked (but nothing appears in the build report)
- continue on error : unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want check "Continue on error" option in VsTest task, please choose "Even if previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled" option in next task's Control Options tab as below screenshot shows.
[image]